# Unsubscribing a subscriber from all subscribers using Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

Hi I have a custom unsubscribe page on which i have a checkbox with submit button.

By using these i want to unsubscribe the subscriber from All subscribers. I am using the below code code and getting 500 internal server error.

```ampscript
    %%[
        IF not empty(requestParameter("submit")) THEN
    
    //SET @subkey = RequestParameter("Subscriberkey")
       // SET @email = RequestParameter("EmailAddress")
    
         SET @subkey = "hardcoded for testing"
        SET @email = "hardcoded for testing"
        
       /* Unsubscribe Subscriber in ET All Subscribers */
    SET @sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
    SetObjectProperty(@sub,"SubscriberKey", @subkey)
    SetObjectProperty(@sub,"Status", "Unsubscribed")
    
    Set @options = CreateObject("UpdateOptions")
    Set @save = CreateObject("SaveOption")
    SetObjectProperty(@save,"SaveAction","UpdateAdd")
    SetObjectProperty(@save,"PropertyName","*")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@options,"SaveOptions", @save)
    
    /* Here is where we actually update the Subscriber object */
    Set @ll_statusCode = InvokeUpdate(@sub, @ll_statusMsg, @update_sub_errorcode, @options)
    
        IF @ll_statusCode == "OK" THEN
            Redirect("https://pub.s4.exacttarget.com/ts2vjt4qghl")
        ELSE
            RaiseError(@ll_statusMsg, 0, @ll_statusCode, @errorCode)
        ENDIF
        
    ENDIF
    ]%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this solution to work. I was using same submit button name with in the page it's throwing error . I  changed the submit button name.

```ampscript
    <!--%%[
    var @subkey
    var @email
    IF not empty(requestParameter("Update")) THEN
    
    SET @subkey = RequestParameter("Subscriberkey")
    SET @email = RequestParameter("EmailAddress")    
        
    /* Unsubscribe Subscriber in ET All Subscribers */
    SET @sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
    SetObjectProperty(@sub,"SubscriberKey", @subkey)
    SetObjectProperty(@sub,"Status", "Unsubscribed")
    
    Set @options = CreateObject("UpdateOptions")
    Set @save = CreateObject("SaveOption")
    SetObjectProperty(@save,"SaveAction","UpdateAdd")
    SetObjectProperty(@save,"PropertyName","*")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@options,"SaveOptions", @save)
    
    /* Here is where we actually update the Subscriber object */
    Set @ll_statusCode = InvokeUpdate(@sub, @ll_statusMsg, @update_sub_errorcode, @options)
    
        IF @ll_statusCode == "OK" THEN
            Redirect("https://pub.s4.exacttarget.com/ts2vjt4qghl")
        ELSE
            RaiseError(@ll_statusMsg, 0, @ll_statusCode, @errorCode)
        ENDIF
        
    ENDIF
    ]%%

-->
```

```html
<br>
<br>
Unsubscribe From All
<br>
<br>

<label>
Text goes here
 </label>
<br>
<br>
 <input id="UnsubscribeAll" type="checkbox" name="UnsubscribeAll" value="AllSubscribers">
  <label>I no longer wish to receive any future publications.
  </label>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update">
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will want to use [LogUnsubEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.htm) instead of Subscriber Object.

> **Why Use the LogUnsubEvent?**
>  Execute Call Use this call when you create
> your own landing page or profile center functionality. Previously, you
> could unsubscribe a subscriber, but you could not create and log the
> UnsubEvent.

**Sample SOAP**

```
<soap-ENV:Body>
    <ExecuteRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Requests>
            <Name>LogUnsubEvent</Name>
            <Parameters>
                <Name>SubscriberID</Name>
                <Value>123456</Value>
            </Parameters>
            <Parameters>
                <Name>SubscriberKey</Name>
                <Value>Key for username@example.com</Value>
            </Parameters>
            <Parameters>
                <Name>EmailAddress</Name>
                <Value>help@example.com</Value>
            </Parameters>
            <Parameters>
                <Name>JobID</Name>
                <Value>18099</Value>
            </Parameters>
            <Parameters>
                <Name>ListID</Name>
                <Value>17914</Value>
            </Parameters>
            <Parameters>
                <Name>BatchID</Name>
                <Value>0</Value>
            </Parameters>
        </Requests>
    </ExecuteRequestMsg>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Comment: Hi Gortonington thanks for the response. I got the subscriber object code to work it was  the requestParameter submit. With in the same page there was another button with the same name that's the root cause for the issue i have.

Comment: Glad you were able to find the solution. Perhaps to help others that have a similar issue, if you could post an answer with your solution and then later accept as the correct answer so that others can reference it.